# Email Notification on when user login

Tags: user-admin, admin

how to get email from workflow rule to alert when someone hasn't logged in after x amount of days. after that user are login then get notification  email .

It means i need notification email from login user when he login after few day.
we can not used trigger ,only used standard functionality .

Please suggest me .

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are asking. See the guidelines for asking a good question [ask]

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in workflow. Create a workflow and give criteria to run `everytime it is edited.`

Now in formula

```
if((PRIORVALUE( LastLoginDate )   - LastLoginDate ) //calculate the difference
```

And set the email alert in the action. This way you can do it without using code.

Note: Using priorValue you will get old value and then compare both values and find the difference and use it.

Comment: Hi sir, Can u tell me how to get email from workflow rule to alert when someone hasn't logged in after x amount of days. it means more than two days.

Comment: @RajeshKr. set the email alert and create an  email template for same. So when your formula meet condition then it will automatically send an email to that user.

Comment: hello sir @tushar how to get email from workflow rule to alert when someone hasn't logged in more than two days .Its not needed workflow you can suggest best solution on salesforce.

Comment: @RajeshKr. If you want to send email if user logged in after two days then workflow will solve your problem.  Otherwise if you want to send email if user not logged in two days then use Batch.

Comment: This workflow is on which object?

Comment: @Shankish on user object.

Comment: It gives me "Field LastLoginDate does not exist. Check spelling" this error.